# spark streaming javaRDD issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I see one issue in my SPARK SQL code, line3 never gets executed, even though line1 has lot of rows, I mean dataFrame2 has rows in it, and the method `call()` never gets executed on the JavaRDD. Please advise, I can't figure this out.

```
listOfDStreams.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>,Void>(){
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        printToLogsAndConsole("listOfDStreams.foreachRDD","listOfDStreams.foreachRDD");
        DataFrame  dataFrame=sqlContext.read().json(rdd);
        DataFrame dataFrame2=null;
        if(dataFrame!=null && rdd!=null&&!rdd.isEmpty()){
            dataFrame.registerTempTable("test");
            dataFrame.groupBy("dst").count().show();
            dataFrame2= sqlContext.sql("select * from test");
            List<Row> rows=dataFrame2.collectAsList(); //line 1
            dataFrame2.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String>() {  //line2
                @Override
                public String call(Row arg0) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    printToLogsAndConsole("in java rdd ","in java rdd");//line3
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you get if you put `dataFrame2.toJavaRDD().count()`?